# Creating dynamic folder and its thumbnail using php

Tags: php

I am creating a folder dynamically, and I want to show the thumbnail of the folder as well.

Here is my index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="pictures">
<form id="pic_form" method="post" action="pictures.php">
<table align="center" width="500" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
   <tr>
   <td width="50px" align="center"/>
   <td width="100px" align="center">Folder Name::
   <td>
   <td width="50px" align="center"/>
   <td width="100px" align="center">
   <input type="text" id="foldername" name="foldername">
   <td>
   <td width="50px" align="center"/>
   <td width="100px" align="center">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create">
   <td>
   <td width="50px" align="center"/>
   </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now here is my pictures.php:

```
<?php
$foldername=$_POST['foldername'];
mkdir("album/$foldername");
//now what to do to generate thumbnail of the folder in the body segment;
//my concept ends here;
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And the question is...? Where would that thumbnail be coming from...?

Comment: thats why i asked it, i dnt knw how to generate thumbnail,

Comment: What is a thumbnail of a folder?

Comment: How do you define "thumbnail" for that folder?! You mean a dynamically created preview of the folder and its contents, [like Windows does](http://thecustomizewindows.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/disable-thumbnail-preview-of-folders-in-Windows-7-1.png)? That's tough! Do you mean a user-uploaded image? Do you mean just a generic folder icon? Be more precise in what you want the result to be!

Comment: well, its kinda like the one in facebook, a folder will be created and a icon or thumbnail will be shown, then if we click on that thumbnail, all the contents(specially images) will be shown again as thumbnail, say for first instance, an empty image album created in facebook

Comment: Facebook simply displays the first (?) image that's in an album, if that's what you mean. It's not a thumbnail of the folder, it's simply the first image in it. And they're certainly not using actual physical folders, they're pulling those from a database. In your case, you just have a folder with nothing in it. What would you expect that thumbnail to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="folder.gif"> <?php echo $_POST['foldername']; ?>
```

Get a folder icon from somewhere and use an `<img>` element to display it. Result looks like this:

> [image] Foobar

Comment: thanx buddy, phew.....that thing cost me some of my reputations....